# Get text from HTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, parsing

I need a way to get all text from my aspx files.
They may contain javascrip also but I only need this for the HTML code.

Basically I need to extract everything on Text or Value attributes, text within code, whatever...

Is there any parser API available?

Cheers!
Alex

Comment: Actually one might respectfully disagree - its a narrower question in that its specific to aspx files and quite possibly a less complex one.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you might consider playing with Linq to XML to strip the interesting stuff out.